# How do I get the current time in a different TimeZone in Java?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, timezone, locale

OK - I feel pretty dumb asking such a basic question, but hey.

I'm trying to get the current time in a different timezone in a Java webapp. I've tried the following obvious solution: in my servlet,

`Calendar localCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(myBean.getTimeZone());`

then I pass the calendar object through to a JSP as a request attribute 'localCalendar':

```
It is now: [${requestScope.localCalendar.time}]
in TimeZone ${requestScope.localCalendar.timeZone.ID}
```

but my output seems to ignore the timezone set, i.e.

`It is now: [Thu Nov 26 10:01:03 GMT 2009] in TimeZone Indian/Mahe`

I'm guessing it's something to do with Locale settings, is there any way to just get the time formatted for my Locale, in another timezone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The internal data of `Calendar` is basically:

> An instant in time can be represented by a millisecond value that is an offset from the Epoch, January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT (Gregorian).

So, it holds a `long` that will be the same no matter what operations you use on it and `toString` makes no promises.

You want to format the date as per locale and timezone. You can do this in the presentation layer (the JSP) using things like [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html) or you can format the date in your bean using a [DateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) and return the value as a string.

Comment: Perfect - the JSTL formatting tags do include a formatDate which takes a timezone attribute. I just wasn't thinking of timezone as a formatting thing... but hey, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to display the date in a given format/timezone, use [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: FYI: This class was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes, with the adoption of JSR 310.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by McDowell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1802789/642706) is correct, but the `java.util.Calendar` (and `java.util.Date`) classes are outmoded.

## java.time

The java.time framework is built into Java 8 and later, and back-ported to Java 6 & 7 and to Android. These new classes supplant the old date-time classes as they have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome.

An `Instant` is the current moment in UTC.

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

Apply a time zone `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

## Time Zone vs Locale

Note that [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) and [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) are orthogonal issues. The time zone affects the [wall clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time), the [offset from UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). `Locale` affects only the presentation. Locale is used for (a) human language for name of day and month, and (b) cultural norms regarding issues such as month before day-of-month, comma versus period, and so on.

For example, you might have a French-reading [Québécois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois_(word)) user accessing your page while working in [India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_India). So use a time zone of [`Asia/Kolkata`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia/Kolkata) with a [`Locale.CANADA_FRENCH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#CANADA_FRENCH).

To generate a formatted string use the [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class. Many example already exist in Stack Overflow. Specify the desired/expected `Locale` via [`withLocale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withLocale-java.util.Locale-) method.