# TimeZone problem in Java

Tags: java, timezone

I am trying to instantiate GregorianCalendar with TimeZone GMT, but whenever I call the getTime() method, it gives me time in local TimeZone. Here is my code:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

The output I am getting is this:

```
Sat Nov 28 19:55:49 PKT 2009
```

Please help!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802758/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-in-a-different-timezone-in-java/1802787#1802787

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but this is one way to get "now" in GMT.

```
import java.text.*
import java.util.* 

Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
Date date = cal.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

See the [Javadoc on SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for different patterns. Also, you may want to consider Joda Time as it is far superior for dates and times.

Comment: +1 for providing a nice detailed example to go with my ramblings, and for suggesting Joda Time. java.util.Date and Calendar are an embarrassment to the Java language.

Comment: Isn't the preferred way of getting a Calendar: Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance() ?

Comment: @kgrad - Calendar is abstract, so you can't do that!

Comment: @Brian: You can't directly instantiate an abstract class, but that doesn't stop you from calling its static methods. Still, I wonder how Calendar knows to return a Gregorian instance? The doc doesn't say, so an implementation is free to return a Mayan calendar??

Comment: How do you get an actual Date instead of a String?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is not with `GregorianCalendar` but with `Date`, which is being used to format the date/time for `toString` for `println`.

If you want control of date formatting, you'll need to instantiate your own `DateFormat` - I always use `SimpleDateFormat` because I'm rather picky about how I want my dates to look.

If you're not interested in the details of how the date is formatted, you can also use one of the `getInstance...` factory methods of `DateFormat`.

You can explicitly `setTimeZone` on a `DateFormat` (including `SimpleDateFormat`, of course).

Comment: he is ecplicitely calling `getTime()`, which returns Date, which, as you say, should be avoided.

Comment: I didn't say that. I said that the way Date formats to a String needs to be avoided.

Comment: ah, I understood the "which is being used", with the Calendar being the "doer", but you meant the qustion-author :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm afraid Michael Esther (sp?) had the better idea when he just sat down and showed how to do it.

Comment: In java8 datetime api `java.time.Instant.now()` will return the current GMT time.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now().toString()
```

> 2020-03-08T00:21:48.647951Z

## `java.util.Date::toString` tells a lie

Your call to `GregorianCalendar::getTime` returns a `java.util.Date`. As you can see with this method and class naming, these classes are badly designed.

Then you implicitly  called `Date::toString` to generate text that represents the value within that object. That value is actually in UTC, being merely a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC. Unfortunately, that method dynamically applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating the text. This creates the illusion of that zone being contained within the object.

Confusing? Yes. One of many reasons to **never use these legacy date-time classes**. Use *java.time* classes instead.

## *java.time*

The other Answers are correct, but now obsolete. The terrible `Date`, `Calendar`, `GregorianCalendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat` classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

To get the current moment in UTC, use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). This basic building block class in *java.time* is always in UTC, by definition.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Generate a string in standard in ISO 8601 format by calling `toString`.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Q9CAQr).

> 2020-03-08T00:21:48.647951Z

For more flexible formatting when generating strings, use the [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class. Search Stack Overflow to learn about `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```