# how can i get Calendar.getInstance() based on Turkey timezone

Tags: java, android, kotlin, timezone

I am developing an android application.
What should I do to get the current time based on Turkish local time?

```
val now = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+3"))
```

the result is:

```
2020-08-25T18:16:30
```

but this website result is different:
https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/turkey/istanbul

```
2020-08-25T16:46:30
```

The output is printed using the following code snippet:

```
DebugHelper.info("one now => ${now.getDisplayMonthNameDayTime(FULL_PATTERN)}")
```

Extention Function:

```
const val FULL_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"

fun Calendar.getDisplayMonthNameDayTime(pattern: String = "dd MMM , HH:mm ") = SimpleDateFormat(
    pattern,
    Locale.getDefault()
).format(time).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault())
```

Comment: **Read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), which clearly lists a [`getInstance(TimeZone zone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance-java.util.TimeZone-) method.

Comment: I have definitely read it, but there was a problem that I asked you dear ones ..
Thank you for your patience in the face of my little knowledge.

Comment: @Andreas You are right, sorry

Comment: *"the result is"* How did you get that result? Simply printing the `Calendar` object doesn't show that specific string.

Comment: @Andreas please check again

Comment: `getDisplayMonthNameDayTime` doesn't set a time zone on the `SimpleDateFormat` it creates, so it works as-if you had called `setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault())`, similar to how you unnecessarily use `Locale.getDefault()`. I don't know Kotlin, so I'm unsure whether `time` refers is the `protected long` field or the `Date getTime()` method, but in either case the value doesn't carry time zone information, so it loses the `TimeZone` assigned to the `Calendar`. Which means that the output is **always in the *default* time zone** of the JVM running the code, regardless of the Calendar's time zone.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a modern and less troublesome API, then use [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), especially `java.time.ZonedDateTime`.

See this minimal example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ZonedDateTime istanbulDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Istanbul"));
    System.out.println(istanbulDateTime);
}
```

Output (some seconds ago):

```
2020-08-25T16:32:56.069+03:00[Europe/Istanbul]
```

As an alternative, there is `ZoneId.of("Asia/Istanbul")`, too, but the values only differ in the description of the continent. Just a matter of taste, I think.

**EDIT**
After your edit I realized you aren't relying on a time zone but rather an offset. That brings in another alternative from `java.time`, that is `java.time.OffsetDateTime`.

For the sake of completeness, here's a possible solution which only takes a `ZoneOffset` without the need to provide a zone by `String`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OffsetDateTime utcPlusThreeDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.ofHours(3));
    System.out.println(utcPlusThreeDateTime);
}
```

which output (a few seconds ago)

```
2020-08-25T16:53:14.490+03:00
```

... and yes, since there's [API desugaring in Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support), you can use it with a suitable gradle plugin.

Comment: thank you.
I can use this method.
my minimum sdk is 21

Comment: I'd go with the ZDT - makes it more future-proof in case Turkey's timezone changes in future, or if they reintroduce daylight savings (they abolished it in 2016).

Comment: @darrengorman totally agree, but OP obviously tried it himself with an offset, that's why I added the solution using `OffsetDateTime` and `ZoneOffset`.

Answer (score 1):

### The solution

Use `ZoneId.of("Asia/Istanbul")` and a `ZonedDateTime` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, as demonstrated in the answer by deHaar.

### The problem

You problem is in this line:

```
).format(time).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault())
```

`time` gives you the time of the `Calendar` object as a `Date` (another poorly designed and long outdated class that we should not use anymore). A `Date` hasn’t got any time zone, so the time zone and offset information from the `Calendar` is lost. So when you format this `Date`, you are using the time zone of the `SimpleDateFormat`, not the time zone of the `Calendar`.

Your `Calendar`’s time zone was `GMT+03:00` alright. As others have mentioned, you should prefer Europe/Istanbul or Asia/Istanbul, though.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Related question: TimeZone problem in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812700/timezone-problem-in-java) (it might even be a duplicate?)

Comment: Thank you very much.
The answer was quite comprehensive and excellent

Answer (score 0):

Turkey have an issue with real time in java...

you need to do you own hack with GMT+03

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+03")
```

code:

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+03");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
```

Comment: thank you, I used this method but unfortunately it shows the current time of the my mobile device.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with using `Europe/Istanbul`? As long as you have an up-to-date Olson database, that is.

Comment: @Andreas please check my question again

Comment: Or Asia/Istanbul if you prefer (it’s an alias for the same).