# Figuring Out Local Time with Adding Manual Hour Method in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime

Hello I have a method which adds a time to my current time.
What I am looking for is I want to add this code a local time info because doesnt get the local time in my country correctly.
I searched in the stackoverflow but couldnt find a similar topic for this case.
I am open your suggestions, thank you.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
      DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
      System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
    }
}
```

I have changed the code with java.time utilities

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");

      LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();
      System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
      System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date.plusHours(10)));  
    }
}
```

Comment: what does it print ? what country and timezone do you have on your machine ? and what should it be ?

Comment: You should immediately stop using `Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`. They are [obsolete and troublesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api). Use classes from the `java.time` package instead.

Comment: @SorinPenteleiciuc I want to use for Turkey

Comment: You should get the timezone from the computer. What do you get UTC ?

Comment: @SorinPenteleiciuc UTC+3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot really use the timezone because you get it from your operating system. If the OS gives you UTC, either configure it to Turkey or change it inside the application.

Since you know your location, just do this:

```
 LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now((ZoneId.of("Europe/Istanbul"));
```

This question from below might help :
[how can i get Calendar.getInstance() based on Turkey timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63579732/how-can-i-get-calendar-getinstance-based-on-turkey-timezone)

You can also deduce your timezone using your internet provider. Below there are 2 examples.

timezone example 1

```
       RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
       String timezone = restTemplate.getForObject("https://ipapi.co/timezone", String.class);
```

timezone example 2

```
        String timezone = restTemplate.getForObject("http://ip-api.com/line?fields=timezone", String.class);
```

After getting the timezone:

```
        LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of(timezone));
```

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to use here. Adding 10 hours will fail when the offset changes, such as Daylight Saving Time.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime
.now( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Istanbul" ) )
.plusHours( 10 )
```

## No, not `Calendar`

Never use the terrible `Calendar` & `SimpleDateFormat` legacy classes.

## No, not `LocalDateTime`

Never call `LocalDateTime.now`. I cannot imagine a case where that is the right thing to do.

The `LocalDateTime` class lacks the context of a time zone or offset from UTC.  So that class cannot represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

To track a moment, use: `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime` classes.

## `ZoneId`

Specify your time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Istanbul" ) ;
```

Or get the JVM‘s current default time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

Get the current moment.

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Add time.

```
ZonedDateTime later = now.plusHours( 10 ) ;
```